# How to read Request.Form values in MVC view of asp.net core project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have asp.net core MVC project and I can't use Request.Form in a view to read form data. What is the alternative to read form data in asp.net core?

The name 'Request' does not exist in the current context.

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    string test = Request.Form["testdata"];   
}
```

Comment: Something is missing, I cannot reproduce this. The code you have posted works fine for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
string test = Context.Request.Form["testdata"];
```

You need to prefix Request with Context.